# purrr use model to data

Tags: r, purrr

I haven't seen anything on my problem. I thought following, when I saw purrr many models examples, that how to use model created on data again? Little bit code will show you what I'm after:

Here is basic gapminder many models example.

```
library(gapminder)
gapminder

by_country <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(country, continent) %>% 
  nest()

country_model <- function(df) {
  lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = df)
}

by_country <- by_country %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, country_model))

by_country %>% 
  mutate(model_lag = lag(model))

# A tibble: 142 x 5
   country     continent data              model    model_lag
   <fct>       <fct>     <list>            <list>   <list>   
 1 Afghanistan Asia      <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: lm> <lgl [1]>
 2 Albania     Europe    <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 
 3 Algeria     Africa    <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 
 4 Angola      Africa    <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 
 5 Argentina   Americas  <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 
 6 Australia   Oceania   <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 
 7 Austria     Europe    <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 
 8 Bahrain     Asia      <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 
 9 Bangladesh  Asia      <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 
10 Belgium     Europe    <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 
# ... with 132 more rows
```

What I thought that instead of just having fitted values with seen data, I could lag model by one and what I would like to do is predict that data with this lagged model. I know this is poor example (why would I use Afghanistan model to Albania), but I have data nested with date, and there it would make sense. This should still be reproducible example. So is there away to use predict in this kind of format?

Result would be new column "pred" [12x1] with predictions on new data and then I could unnest that with data and have predictions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `purrr::map2`. I'm not quite sure how to get it to evaluate on the `NA` value, so I just filter that out.

```
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% 
  group_by(country, continent) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, partial(lm, lifeExp ~ year))) %>% 
  mutate(model_lag = lag(model)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(model_lag)) %>%
  mutate(pred = map2(model_lag, data, predict))
```

Comment: we can wrap possibly(predict, NA) in the map2, thanks for answer.